# Errno=9 bad file descriptor in php

Tags: php, file

Im trying to write a file in php with the following code

```
    $filename = "uploads/stories/".$row['s_source'];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    if (filesize($filename) == 0) {
      $txt = "{====views====}{====likes====}{====chapters====}{====comments====}";
      fwrite($handle, $txt);
    }
    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
```

And I get:

> Notice: fwrite(): write of 66 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor in E:\xampp\htdocs\host\host\storyedit.php on line 20
>
> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in E:\xampp\htdocs\host\host\storyedit.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\host\host\storyedit.php on line 27

But there is no error (I think) in the code. Could someone help me?

I've tried:

1. Deleting opcache.enable_cli=1 in php.ini
2. Deleting cache

none worked.

Comment: Did the $filename exist  and filesize($filename) == 0 ?

Comment: Note, even if you open with write access, this error can happen if another process writes to the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You open with reading access `r` and then you give a write command `>`. You need to open with read/write access:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
```

In relation to error in `fread`, try:

```
if (filesize($filename) > 0) {
    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having this error, it can be as well just opening file with mode 'a'. Using mode 'r' to read files is the right way.